# Convert a list to a string without a break line

Tags: python, string, list

I converted a list to a string, but how can I get rid of the line break between the list items?

It should only delete the line break between the two classmaps, not the whole formatting.

```
    def config_classmap(self, classmapdict):
        self.classmaplist = []
        if self.voice > 0:
            voiceclass = f'''
class cos-map-dscp-vo-2
  police {self.voice * 1000} conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
  priority
'''
            self.classmaplist.append(voiceclass)
        for key, value in classmapdict.items():
            if value[0] > 0:
                classmap = f'''
class {key}
  bandwidth {value[0]}
  queue-limit {value[1]}
'''
                self.classmaplist.append(classmap)
            else:
                continue
        self.classmaps = "".join(self.classmaplist)
        return self.classmaps

    def __str__(self):
       return "{0}".format(self.classmaps)
```

OUTPUT:

```
# class cos-map-dscp-vo-2
#   police 1000000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
#   priority
#
# class cos-map-dscp-vs-2
#   bandwidth 500
#   queue-limit 83
```

SHOULD LOOK LIKE:

```
# class cos-map-dscp-vo-2
#   police 1000000 conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
#   priority
# class cos-map-dscp-vs-2
#   bandwidth 500
#   queue-limit 83
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may not notice this but there is a line break in your code.

right here:

```
def config_classmap(self, classmapdict):
    self.classmaplist = []
    if self.voice > 0:
        voiceclass = f'''
class cos-map-dscp-vo-2
  police {self.voice * 1000} conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
 priority
'''
```

should be:

```
def config_classmap(self, classmapdict):
    self.classmaplist = []
    if self.voice > 0:
        voiceclass = f'''
class cos-map-dscp-vo-2
  police {self.voice * 1000} conform-action transmit exceed-action drop
 priority'''
```

Alternatively, don't start with a line break:

```
    for key, value in classmapdict.items():
        if value[0] > 0:
            classmap = f'''class {key}
  bandwidth {value[0]}
  queue-limit {value[1]}
'''
```